# Brownian Motion and covariance matrix

Tags: r

Given a vector t. How can I fill a matrix like

```
t[1] t[1] t[1] ... t[1]  
t[1] t[2] t[2] ... t[2]  
t[1] t[2] t[3] ... t[3]  
...  ...  ...  ...  ...  
t[1] t[2] t[3] ... t[n]
```

that corresponds to a covariance matrix for Brownian motion at times t?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way.

```
t <- 11:15
m <- vapply(seq_along(t), function(i) c(t[seq_len(i)], rep(t[i], length(t)-i)), numeric(length(t)))
m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]   11   11   11   11   11
#[2,]   11   12   12   12   12
#[3,]   11   12   13   13   13
#[4,]   11   12   13   14   14
#[5,]   11   12   13   14   15
```

You could use `sapply` too - a bit shorter but also a bit slower (you don't specify what the function returns):

```
m <- sapply(seq_along(t), function(i) c(t[seq_len(i)], rep(t[i], length(t)-i)))
```

Answer (score 4):

The value of the (i,j) coefficient is min(i,j):

```
m <- matrix( NA, nr=5, nc=5 ) # Empty matrix with the right size
m <- pmin( col(m), row(m) )
```

Comment: Looks like this solution is a bit faster than @Tommy's.

Comment: @Vincent I tried to generalize your answer to general vector t, as follows  `m <- pmin(t[col(m)], t[row(m)])` but this give me a vector of size nc*nr, so I applied the matrix command again

Comment: That should be 
`pmin(col(t), row(t))`,
if your matrix is really called `t`.
I changed the name of the matrix from `t` to `m`
because `t` is already the transpose function.